# Have one controller function call a different controller function in CakePHP 1.2

Tags: cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.2

How do I get my `Search` controller with `doSearch()` function internally to call `getTitles()` function in my `Titles` controller?

Comment: One thing would be to move it into the app_controller but lets try without that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is, *you shouldn't do this*. You should be moving that to your Title model or maybe put it in a component or helper for reuse.

If you're sure you want to call the controller directly, Cake does provide a method for this

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction

Comment: you're right it should be a component (its not db related, just some php processing) but you can also do it like this          App::import('Controller','Titles');
       $title_controller = new TitlesController();

Comment: @chris you shouldn't import your controller into another controller. Doesn't feel 'right' to me. Component would be the best way I think.

Comment: It is working for me also good, but if i have to set a variable on another controller it do not set. i also tried with session.
for example in this case in titlesController if i have to set a variable $this->set('s', 's'); it is not working. and similar $this->Session->write('s', 's'); not working.
Any Help ?

Comment: @GovindTotla You should create a new question to ask this. Please include all details.

Comment: The link above has been moved to http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#requestaction

Comment: Thank you for actually answering the question well, while explaining that it is still possible although not advisable. I need this functionality for a prototype due at end of day, so this work around is suitable for my purposes. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

there is no reason to go to a another controller.

controller should mostly call methods from models. so there should be a Title Model that contains the method you need.

Post your code if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer, for future reference, is:

```
$this->requestAction('/controller/action/params');
```

Answer (score 0):

Making functionality that you want to reuse components does not always work well as Cakephp, does not bring in Models and find(), and set->$this etc. One other way to go is make your core functionality a core function then return $results, call this functionality like $results =$this->function_within_controller(); so you can reuse the functionality this way. I run into alsorts of errors when sometimes trying to use components, in Cakephp, components is good for using standalone php scripts and code.